# Show More / Show Less Toggle on a Section within Elemenor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to achieve a **show more/show less** function on my product page, built with Elementor Page Builder. Kinda Like [this](https://codepen.io/ojbravo/pen/YPJpXe) with the fade also, but using JS.

I currently have this setup on my [My Product Page](https://www.simplylifting.co.uk/lifting-web-sling-3-tonne/). It's not quite what I want as the section is completely hidden and then is revealed on-click.

I have achieved this by doing the following:

- 1no. Section with 1 Column.
- Within this, 2no. 'inner section widgets'.
- Top 'inner section' houses a product description widget. The 'inner
  section' of this has been given a CSS ID of 'hiddenBlock'

I have then added the following custom CSS to this:

```
    #hiddenBlock {
Display:none;
}
```

- The bottom 'inner section' widget houses the 'button widget'. The
  budget widget has been given the CSS ID of 'showBlock'

Then I've added some custom JS using another plugin as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

   $('#showBlock').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   $('#hiddenBlock').fadeToggle("slow");
 });
});
```

However, how would I go about achieving what I mentioned where the section can be partially viewed and then completely revealed on-click. I'd ideally like the button text to change also when its clicked, to say 'show less' or something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you using **.toggle()**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   $('#showBlock').click(function(e) {
       $('#hiddenBlock').toggle();
       e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the response. However, it doesn't make too much difference whether I use .toggle() or .fadeToggle(). That just changes the style of the toggle itself.